# Copy file to different directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, file-manager

Let's say I have a file at the path /documents/recording.caf and I want to copy it into the folder /documents/folder. How would I do this? If I want to use the following code, it appears as though I have to include the file name and extension in the path, which I will not always know.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *newPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/temporary/recording.caf"];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newPath] == NO) {

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:file toPath:newPath error:&error];

    }

}
```

A tableview is updated with every file it finds in a directory and if the user taps a cell, I want to copy this file somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe I'm not totally clear on your question, but why do you think you will have to know the file name & extension in the path?  You could just pick up the filename + extension from the original `file` that's being passed into this routine and insert the new path in place of the old path (i.e. preserving the filename + extension) via NSString's `lastPathComponent` method.

Comment: On a side note what not move the file instead of copying it?  Do you really need two physical copies of this file?

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner It's for uploading a file to my server. I want the files to have a specific name (username_filename.fileextension). I'm sure I could rename it somewhere else, but as not having any experience with PHP, this is easiest for me. The files aren't big and are temporary, so it will work for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the appended path component is also a string, you could use another create another string with the file name that you do not know

```
NSString *anotherString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/temporary/%@",<yourfilenameAsString>];
```

and just append that to newPath.

I would also suggest that you should not be constructing paths like @"/temporary/filename.extension". But rather, you construct it as using the path construction methods of NSString like

```
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)aString
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathExtension:(NSString *)ext
```

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't be writing to the root directory of the device ('/'), instead, you should write to the user's documents directory.